# Variational derivative of a Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mathematics, variational-principle, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I would like to know how exactly to calculate the variational derivative of:
$$L = \oint dx \: \frac{m}{a} (\dot{u}(x,t))^2 - ca(u'(x,t)^2\tag{1}$$
with respect to $u$, ($\delta L / \delta u$).
The variable $x$ is integrated over a closed loop defined on an interval from $0$ to some length $a$ where $u(0) = u(a)$.

Following my lecture notes, the result is meant to be $$\delta L / \delta u = cau''\tag{2}$$ but whatever I do I don't get the integral over $x$ canceled. I have also used partial integration and the fact that $$\frac{\delta}{\delta u} = \frac{\partial \:\delta}{\partial x\: \delta u'}\tag{3}$$ and tried to treat the expression as a partial derivative in $u$, but somehow I never get rid of the closed integral.
Hopefully someone might be able to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know how exactly to calculate the variational derivative of:
> $$L = \oint dx \: \frac{m}{a} \dot{u}(x,t) - ca(u')^2$$
> with respect to $u$, ($\delta L / \delta u$).
> Following my lecture notes, the result is meant to be $$\delta L / \delta u = cau''$$ but whatever I do I don't get the integral over $x$ canceled.

The variational derivative is a functional derivative, which is **defined** to be just the part that is integrated against $\delta u$ to get $\delta L$.

$$
\delta L = \int dx \frac{\delta L}{\delta u(x)}\delta u(x)
$$

This is why you "cancel" the integral to arrive at the expression for $\delta L/\delta u(x)$.

Comment: I get your point, thank you. that also explains why there is still some riemann integration apparent.